# ldap auth on nodejs - keep getting 32 No Such Object

Tags: node.js, ldap

I am an LDAP newbie.

I am using nodejs's [ldapauth](https://github.com/trentm/node-ldapauth) and I keep getting `32 - No Such Object`.

Here is my code :

```
var LdapAuth = require('ldapauth');
var ldapOptions = {
    "url":"ldap://my-host:389",
    "adminDn" : "cn=manager,dc=guycrc,dc=com",
    "adminPassword":"secret",
    "searchBase":"ou=Engineering",
    "searchFilter":"(uid={{username}})"
};

var ldapAuthClient = new LdapAuth( ldapOptions );

ldapAuthClient.authenticate('Dana', 'Dana',
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(['Error',err.code, err.dn, err.message ]);
        } else {
            console.log('Credentials valid = ' + result); // true or false
        }
    }
);
```

This is my LDAP info - what I think is relevant for the question

```
dn: cn=Dana,ou=people,dc=guycrc,dc=com
...
cn: Dana Dana
sn: Dana
uid: Dana
userpassword: Dana
ou: Engineering


dn: cn=CompanyA,ou=groups,dc=guycrc,dc=com
...
cn: CompanyA
ou: Groups
member: cn=Dana,ou=people,dc=guycrc,dc=com
```

Why am I getting `No Such Object` all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being sure what the `.authenticate` is meant to do in your line:
`ldapAuthClient.authenticate('Dana', 'Dana',`

I would guess that the data passed is not sufficient to find the required object, per the error.

Looking at your defined options:

```
"searchBase":"ou=Engineering",
"searchFilter":"(uid={{username}})"
```

Means that it is looking in the ou=engineering container.  And looking for a uid that matches username, so probably the 'Dana' as the uid part is correct.

But since your LDIF shows Dana with the DN: 
`dn: cn=Dana,ou=people,dc=guycrc,dc=com`

Not in an ou=engineering.

Perhaps it as simple as changing your searchBase to ou=people,dc=guycrc,dc=com

Comment: I modified "searchBase" to "dc=guycrc,dc=com" and it worked. does this sound logical?

Comment: @guymograbi Yes, changing the searchbase as you did looks much better.  basically it is telling LDAP where to start looking from and down deeper.  Needs to be a valid starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The search base object `ou=engineering` is probably not what is intended, that value does not look like a DN, but rather like an RDN. Use the complete and correct search base object, which will be a DN superior to the objects for which the client searches.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Search Best Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)

Comment: The link you gave me looks like a really good resource for LDAP. Do you have any more like it? I am looking for a short read on the basics.